# Inkscape poor performance and lags on powerfull machine

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, intel-graphics, inkscape

I have problem with Inkscape. Even with relatively small file I see delay when I move text field or graphic elements. There are few seconds lags although the PC has enough memory and CPU and Inkscape tooks about 500 MB RAM and few % of CPU.

My PC specs (system is 64bit Kubuntu Trusty Tahr):

> Summary
>
> Computer Processor    4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
>   Memory    16310MB (6164MB used)
>  Operating System  Ubuntu 14.04.1
>   LTS
>  Display Resolution    1920x1200 pixels
>  OpenGL
>   Renderer  Unknown
>  X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation

Graphics:

> VGA compatible controller Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen
>   Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00
>   [VGA controller])

Console output:

> juhele@Hosaka-Cyberspace7:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
>  00:02.0
>   VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200
>   v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412]
>   (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
>           Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
>           Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
>           Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
>           Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
>           I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
>           Expansion ROM at  [disabled]
>           Capabilities: 
>           Kernel driver in use: i915
>
> 00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen
>   Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
>           Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2010]
>           Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47 juhele@Hosaka-Cyberspace7:~$

Inkscape is official from repository: Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939
Already tried complete wipe of Inkscape, deleting settings in /home, then fresh install. Problem still remains.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 4th generation Intel Haswell chip-set requires the i965 driver.

one has to build mesa with option:

```
--with-dri-drivers=i965
```

for debug: [intel_gpu_top](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/intel_gpu_top.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with PPA update to version 0.91: https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable